# Subtraction in a while loop

Tags: while-loop, subtraction

I am fairly new to the programing game. And usually when I run into problems I can fix them quite quickly with little help. however this on has me stumped.

I am attempting to build a basic calculator of sorts, and I'm using while loops to do it.

Addition was simple because all I had to do was type:

`sum += a`

However subtraction, multiplication, and division will not be as easy. I was wondering if someone would point me in the right direction as like I said before I am stumped.

Here is a part of my code for reference:

```
    x = 0;

    while(x < y){
        if(operator == 1){          /*addition portion*/

    x += 1;
    printf("Please enter number %d: ", x);
    scanf("%lf", &a);

        sum += a;}

        else if(operator == 2){     /*subtracion portion*/
    x += 1;
    printf("Please enter number %d: ", x);
    scanf("%lf", &b);

        sum += b - sum;}}               /*NOT WORKING, FIX, RESEARCH*/

    printf("\nThe sum of the entered numbers = %.f\n\n", sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use other operators like `-=`, `*=`, and `/=` for subtraction, multiplication, and division, respectively.  For example:

```
sum -= c; // equivalent to "sum = sum - c;"
sum *= d; // equivalent to "sum = sum * d;"
sum /= e; // equivalent to "sum = sum / e;"
```

(By the way, you can find big [tables of all the operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++) in various places.  They might be a little overwhelming at the moment, but they'll be great reference later on!)